# Creating multiple Objects containing a dynamic variable and assigning values to its attributes within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have an issue with how to create multiple Objects having variables within their names and assign values to attributes, all this within the context of a loop.

The javascript code is on the bottom of the question.

Basically, in my current code, the following code is working:

```
window['stBgAsset'+stId] = new Image();
```

Effectively, it creates
stBgAsset15 = new Image() and stBgAsset23 = new Image() 
This works as in Chrome Dev Tools when I type: stBgAsset15
it returns img.

But as soon as I try to give an attribute to these Objects (while staying inside the 'for' loop), it does not work as I tried to access it on chrome dev tool's console and it said undefined.

For example, when I use 'stBgAsset'+stId.imageloaded = 1;
, what I mean is "set the following things while looping the for loop"

```
stBgAsset15.imageloaded = 1
stBgAsset23.imageloaded = 1
and so on...
```

Likewise when I put afterClickOnButton('stBgAsset'+stId); at the end of the loop, what I mean is "set the following things while looping the for loop"

```
afterClickOnButton('stBgAsset15');
afterClickOnButton('stBgAsset23');
```

Today I run into 2 big issues with the current code:

1. It's not working (biggest issue)
   I am certain because when I type in Dev tools 'stBgAsset15.imageloaded' it outputs "undefined"
2. Secondary less important issue: I know I am polluting the global namespace and would like a cleaner/more secure javascript way to do this, if it's possible and relevant to what I am doing, than using this window[].

**storyObject**

```
// main object is a array made of json elements
// of course this is an example and comes from  the database. We have no way to know before if id is 15 and 23.it changes for each page loaded
StoryObject =
[ {"id":15,
   "name": "name1",
   "filename":"img5.jpg"},
  {"id":23,
   "name": "name2",
   "filename":"img7.jpg"},
  //...and so on

]
```

**JS Code**

```
//iterating through each json of the above array
for (var i = 0; i < storyObject.length; i++) {
    var currentObject = storyObject[i];

    var stId          = currentObject.id;
    var stFilename    = currentObject.filename; 

    var jqueryCurrentShellImg = $('#content').find('#asset-'+stId);   

    //ISSUE IS HERE
    // I want to create names with variable number inside
    // creating this way 
    // stBgAsset15 = new Image() and stBgAsset23 = new Image() 
    window['stBgAsset'+stId] = new Image();

    jqueryCurrentShellImg.on('load', function(e) {
      console.log("image XXX downloaded");      
      'stBgAsset'+stId.imageloaded = 1;
      console.log('value: '+'stBgAsset'+stId);
    }); 

    afterClickOnButton('stBgAsset'+stId);         

  }

function afterClickOnButton(data) {
  //some actions here where i need to have stBgAsset15 and stBgAsset23 passed
}
```

Comment: Are you just randomly inserting the `_`? `stBgAsset15` and `stBgAsset_15` are not the same String. And you can't have an expression to the left of `=`. You need `window['stBgAsset'+stId].imageloaded = 1;`

Comment: Small error in the question. Mistyped. Will edit now

Comment: I tried window['stBgAsset'+stId].imageloaded=1 already but it was not assigning the value.

Comment: I'd like to anyhow move away if possible from global variable but don't really know how

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store additional information right inside `StoryObject`.

```js
var StoryObject = [{
    "id": 15,
    "name": "name1",
    "filename": "img5.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "name2",
    "filename": "img7.jpg"
  }
];

StoryObject.forEach((so, i) => {
  $('#content').find('#asset-' + so.id).on('load', function () {
    so.imageloaded = true;
    console.log(so.filename + " loaded successfully");
  });
  afterClickOnButton(so);
});

function afterClickOnButton(data) {
  //some actions here where i need to have stBgAsset15 and stBgAsset23 passed
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <img id="asset-15" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <img id="asset-23" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150">  
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty clever, i had totally ignored the ability to use storyObject! I ´ll try

Answer (score 0):

'stBgAsset'+stId.imageloaded = 1; won't work.

You need to do
    window['stBgAsset'+stId].imageloaded = 1;

Otherwise, an imageloaded property is added to the stId variable.

As for your second question, there are multiple ways to limit global namespace pollution, or to prevent it altogether.

One way is to namespace it by creating a root object. So instead of:

```
window[object15]=1;
```

Or the equivalent

```
window.object15=1;
```

You do

```
window.myNamespace = {};
window.myNamespace[object15]=1;
```

Or you could do everything in function scope:

```
(function () {
    var object15=1;
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    b.onClick=function(){
        alert(object15);
    };
})();
```

The local function variables are completely isolated from global namespace. In this example, the value is shown to be reserved, as it is displayed when the body is clicked.